# Restrict enum values defined in a separate JSONschema

Tags: json, validation, enums, schema

I have a simple enums only schema separately to the payload schema say like this

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "demo::common::Husbandry",
    "properties": {
        "Anilmals": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Anilmals"
        },
        "Breeds": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Breeds"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "Anilmals": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Any animal",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 30,
            "enum": [
                "Dog",
                "Cat",
                "Bear",
                "Human"
            ]
        },
        "Breeds": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Any Breed",
            "minLength": 1,
            "maxLength": 30,
            "enum": [
                "Poodle",
                "Cheshire",
                "Polar",
                "Trump"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If I/payload producer was to send out a stricter schema over this to express and code additional rules without violating the original schema, **Example** - *When Animal chosen was "Cat" they can only choose "Cheshire" as a Breed* and so on how would I code the stricter schema? Note the original schema is not changeable and readonly. I may need to use **anyOf** or **oneOf** but can't seem to find a good example.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "ReferenceToLocalSchema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/LocalType"
        },
        "ReferenceToExternalSchema": {
            "$ref": "masterh-husbandry.json#/properties"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "LocalType": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "no-write": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```